# Android: How can I detect if the Back button will exit the app (i.e. this is the last activity left on the stack)?

Tags: android, button, android-activity, exit, back

I'd like to warn the user if the back press is going to finish the last activity on the stack, thereby exiting the app. I'd like to pop up a little toast and detect a 2nd back press within the next few seconds and only then call `finish()`.

I already coded the back press detection using `onBackPressed()`, but I can't find an obvious way to see how many activities are left on the back stack.

Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The reddit is fun app does this [by overriding the onKeyDown method](https://github.com/talklittle/reddit-is-fun/blob/master/src/com/andrewshu/android/reddit/threads/ThreadsListActivity.java#L273):

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    //Handle the back button
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && isTaskRoot()) {
        //Ask the user if they want to quit
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
        .setTitle(R.string.quit)
        .setMessage(R.string.really_quit)
        .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //Stop the activity
                finish();    
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton(R.string.no, null)
        .show();

        return true;
    }
    else {
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Comment: isTaskRoot() seems like the cleanest method without requiring extra permissions. I think this is the winner.

Comment: What is mSettings here?

Comment: @berserk mSettings is just the a reference to the application settings determining if we want to display confirmation dialog or not. it's not critical in this example.

Comment: It is not detecting if this is the final activity. It is returning false. I was having only one activity left in stack.

Comment: isTaskRoot() returns true even if back does not result in exiting the app. i.e..., if you are displaying a bunch of fragments

Answer (score 3):

The [droid-fu](https://github.com/kaeppler/droid-fu) library does this by checking the stack of running tasks and seeing if the next task is the android home screen. See `handleApplicationClosing` at https://github.com/kaeppler/droid-fu/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/droidfu/activities/BetterActivityHelper.java.

However, I would only use this approach as a last resort since it's quite hacky, won't work in all situations, and requires extra permissions to get the list of running tasks.

Comment: No idea why they chose to check for an explicit Android launcher rather than for their own package, but this put me on the right track.